# Frames of reference: Inertial and accelerated - and jerked, snapped, crackled and popped?

Tags: acceleration, reference-frames, jerk

There are inertial frames of reference and the accelerated frames of reference, but are there any frames of references w.r.t. higher order derivatives of velocity? [[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_%28physics%29) [[2]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snap,_Crackle,_and_Pop#Physics)

For example, jerked frames of reference, snapped frames of reference, crackled frames of reference and popped frames of reference and so on?

Comment: Of course there are, *by definition*. They're not exactly inertial, though.

Comment: A jerked frame of reference *is* an accelerated frame of reference, since in general nonzero jerk requires nonzero acceleration (except perhaps at certain instants). The only thing physically special about a frame with *constant* acceleration is that the fictitious forces are constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  For simplicity, consider an observer $O'$ moving in one dimension.  Suppose that as measured by some other inertial observer $O$, the obsever $O'$ has the following position as a function of time
\begin{align}
  x(t) = kt^n
\end{align}
where $n$ is an integer.  When $n=2$ or higher, the observer has nonzero acceleration, so the a frame of reference in which he is at rest is accelerating.  For $n=3$ or higher, the corresponding frame of reference will have nonzero jerk. For $n=4$ or higher...well you get the picture.

The only problem is that for $n=4$ or greater, rice crispies start appearing all over the place, and it gets really hard to make measurements.

Comment: Rice crispies??

Comment: @PeterMortensen http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snap,_Crackle,_and_Pop#Physics

Answer (score 1):

A frame of reference does not need to be inertial though, for a non-inertial frame of reference, there is, at any instant, a momentarily co-moving (*inertial*) reference frame or [MCRF](http://physicspages.com/2011/05/25/acceleration-in-special-relativity/)

> Now suppose that a particle does accelerate. In that case, we can have
>   an inertial frame at any event in the particle’s life by defining the
>   momentarily comoving reference frame or MCRF for short. This is a
>   reference frame that, at a given event, has the same velocity as the
>   particle. If the particle is accelerating, then the MCRF will change
>   from one event to the next, but at each point it is always an inertial
>   frame.

Note that there is no requirement that the acceleration is *uniform*.